# Orchard alternate style for a form

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, content-management-system, orchardcms

i am new to orchard but im trying to create an alternate style for a custom form. I am using the designer tool to try to get the right naming conventions for the text boxes but it seems to be no help. This is the current call for my text box
   `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)`. This doesnt seem to work is there a set method to get the correct naming conventions for a text box using the designer tool?

Comment: Designer tools are only going to help with shapes. `Html.TextBoxFor` is from MVC, not from Orchard, so it's not a shape, it has no alternates, etc. Instead, alternate the shape above that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any clear idea by your question.

But answering by experience. i'll describe to you what I would do to create an alternate for my form:

- Alternates are added for the whole View, rather than individual html components. You'll create an alternate View for your form.
- Alternate created by Designer Tools goes to your active Theme. Cut it from there and paste it in you module's View folder, it will provide you the whole functionality,model, classes etc of your module.
- Then write the razor view as you want and it will work.